# WSL2 /ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mariadb, windows-subsystem-for-linux

sorry for my english

I try to install zabbix in a ubuntu 20.04 who is running in a WSL Windows10 ( for school training)

When i try to connect to mariadb ,this message appear:

**ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)**

i saw similar questions , in the forum but i don't find anyone who specificly talk about WSL.

thank you for helping!

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs in WSL because mysql or mariadb is installed but is not running yet.

Use  `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start` to start the server.

If this doesn't work you might also had an error during installation because it couldn't set the runlevel.
In my case I had to deinstall mysql/mariadb and install it as follows:

```
sudo su
export RUNLEVEL=1
apt install mysql-server
/etc/init.d/mysql start
```